# Why is my Thymeleaf can't parse th:href command?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

all I'm new to SpringBoot and I'm trying to create a simple project with Thymeleaf. I've created the link mapping and when I typed the url manually it works. The template renders succesfully. However, right now I'm currently trying to use Thymeleaf feature such as the th:href on  tag. But it does nothing and instead, treat my  tag like a normal text.

I've searched around and I'm sure the Thymeleaf engine didn't parse the command to browser, they still read it as  instead of . However, I have no idea how to solve this problem because I'm new. So, I created a test html to point to my available template which has been declared on the controller. Also, I've put all of my html files on templates folder.

Below is the code for test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="register.hrml" th:href="@{/register.html}">href th:href</a>
    <a th:href="@{/register.html}">th:href</a>
    <a href="register.html">Normal Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for AppsController.java

```
package com.testapp.travelmu;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AppsController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegister(){
        return "register";
    }
}
```

[and this is the captured output when I run the test.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HHCt.png)

I hope someone can give me direction on how to solve this because I still haven't found the explicit direction on how to solve this problem. Thymeleaf doesn't give out an error either. From this problem I'm sure other th:xx syntax will also face the same error so I hope I could make thymeleaf run like its supposed to do.

Comment: Did you list `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` as a dependency for your project? Either in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, depending on what you use.

Comment: If you did, then you perhaps just need to put your HTML templates into the correct directory. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.customize-view-resolvers) and search for "thymeleaf" within that document.

Comment: You mention a `test.html` but your controller doesn't do anything to render that page. So where is your `test.html` located...

Comment: @AlexR Yup. It's already added on my pom.xml. I've also placed html templates to main>java>resources>templates folder..

Comment: @M.Deinum its located on the template folder to. I access that page manually by typing in the file and it contains link to one of my route in some form as example. As you can see, the one in form <a th:href> is not parsed on the browser to <a href> like it should

Comment: `main/java/resources` is the wrong folder. It should be in `src/main/resources/templates` and you cannot access it directly, you should go through a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your html tag is missing a XML namespace.

Try to add it by replacing

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

with

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried this and nothing change. I've also tried to rebuild and rerun the apps, no change unfortunately. Browser still seeing th:href instead of href..

Answer (score 0):

Link should not contain .html extension. Controller takes care of this when parsing templates.

Replace

```
<a th:href="@{/register.html}">th:href</a>
```

with

```
<a th:href="@{'/register'}">Register</a>
```

Note /register is the GetMapping in your controller.

Also remember to add the missing XML namespace as in the answer above.

Finally you should rename your test.html to register.html

But if it must be test.html, then in controller you should return "test" instead of return "register"

Comment: Yup. You're right. Adding the missing xml namespace and using the tag as such works. I've tried those before but it still didn't work. Turns out the main problem is my browser cache probably. I run the apps in incognito tab and it all works. It's a weird bug, really.